# Can the Tower capture the Wagon and/or the Mayor in Carcassonne

Tags: carcassonne

When playing Carcassonne with "The Tower" and "Abbey and Mayor" expansions, can adding a level to the tower capture either the Mayor and/or Wagon?

There are no rules that I have seen that either authorize and/or forbid doing this so it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the file Carcassonne CAR (this is the link https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/87531/carcassonne-standard-complete-annotated-rules ) page 52, section the tower, before note 120 says: "Whenever a player places a tower piece, he or she may take one follower prisoner. Builders and pigs cannot be taken prisoner" So any meeple than can be considered a follower and it's not a pig or a builder can be captured.

In page 57, section abbey and mayor, note 137 says: "The mayor and wagon are followers, subject to the usual rules of deployment and affecting the majority. The barn is a special figure, not a follower.".

Comment: Wow, didn't know this document existed, thanks for the information.